# Is there any difference between DECIMAL and NUMERIC in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

[Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#decimal_types) just tells us that "DECIMAL is an alias for NUMERIC". Is there any differences?

Comment: I think alias means its the same type. In legacy SQL BigQuery there only was numeric, but no decimal data type. I guess they leaved it for historical reasons.

Comment: Just so you know why the four answers you posted in the last 24 hours were deleted, read [how not to be a spammer](/help/promotion). All of those four answers were barely more than a link to your own blog, without you mentioning that it is indeed your own blog. That makes it spam, especially when you do it more often.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference semantically. If we have to name one difference, it could be that if you check the table schema (through UI or INFORMATION_SCHEMA), only NUMERIC will ever appear, which is why DECIMAL is only a `alias` not a real type.